# Can my main menu go out of memory as I segue to the game on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am creating a game on iOS. So far I only have a simple main menu view controller and a game view controller, the main menu has a button that segues (modal) to the game view controller. I put an NSLog in the - (void)dealloc method of the main menu VC, and it never printed, so I am assuming that the main menu would still be in memory as I am playing the game. Should I worry about this or is there a better way to deal with this?;

In my mind, the ideal situation would be to segue to the game VC, have the main menu go out of memory, then when I want to go back to the main menu, have it re-initialized.

Thank you.

Comment: If you need to worry about the memory used by your main menu view controller, you have bigger problems. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I see, now that I think about it, I was being a bit too paranoid about that tiny bit of memory xP, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the view controller will automatically go out if needed.

Unless you have a major memory issue, a simple main screen won't cause you a problem.